# Solving Optimal Control with non linear cost function

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I am trying to solve the Kermak Mc-Kendrick SIR model using a non linear cost function, but I am stuck on how to possibly solve it.

I need to find an optimal control $u(t)$ in $[0,T]$ that minimize:

$min J = S(T) + \int\limits_{0}^{T} [u(t)S(t)]^2 dt$

with

$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = - \lambda  S(t)  [1 - S(t) - R(t)]  - S(t)u(t)$,

$\frac{\partial R}{\partial t} = \gamma [1-S(t)-R(t)]$,

$S(t),R(t)\geq 0$,
$ S(0) = s_0, R(0) = 0$.

It represents the evolution of an epidemic, where S(.) are the sane nodes, and R(.) the nodes that have recovered. The goal is to infect the most of the users by $T$, taking into account a quadratic cost for direct promotion (the $S(t)u(t)$ term) .

Classical optimal control does not work because of the non linear term in the cost function. Thanks in advance to anyone that will point me in the right direction.

Comment: I would reduce this problem to the classical changing control function $v(t)=S(t)u(t)$. Then solving this and obtaining $v(t),S(t)$ you will get the origianl $u(t)=v(t)/S(t)$. BTW the term $S(t)$ in the cost function is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, I meant S(T). Thank you for the correction

Comment: Then with $v(t)=S(t)u(t)$ the problem becomes  classical, do you agree? However, you equation for $S(t)$ is not linear, so I am not sure that the analytical solution exists.

Comment: Yeah, that's right thank you!!